# Flask SqlAlchemy :sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'ApiAgent' is not mapped

Tags: python, inheritance, flask, sqlalchemy

I try to deal with inheritance models and sqlAlchemy, flask and flask_sqlalchemy.

The following code is working if inline :

wf_agent.py

```
from app import db
class WFAgent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wf_agent'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    agent_type = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': agent_type,
                   'polymorphic_identity': 'wf_agent'}
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

class ApiAgent(WFAgent):
    __tablename__ = 'wf_agent'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'api_agent'}

    api_key = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    token = db.Column(db.String(1024))

    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

populate.py

```
from app import db

from app.models.agent.wf_agent import  WFAgent, ApiAgent

db.drop_all()
db.configure_mappers()
db.create_all()
db.session.commit()


api_agent = WFAgent(name="agent 1")
db.session.add(api_agent)

api_agent = ApiAgent(name="agent 2")
db.session.add(api_agent)

db.session.commit()
```

But it doesnt work if I split in 2 files :

wf_agent.py

```
from app import db
class WFAgent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wf_agent'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    agent_type = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': agent_type,
                   'polymorphic_identity': 'wf_agent'}
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

api_agent.py

```
from app import db
from agent.wf_agent import WFAgent

class ApiAgent(WFAgent):
    __tablename__ = 'wf_agent'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'api_agent'}

    api_key = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    token = db.Column(db.String(1024))

    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

populate.py

```
from app import db

from app.models.agent.wf_agent import  WFAgent
from app.models.agent.api_agent import  ApiAgent

db.drop_all()
db.configure_mappers()
db.create_all()
db.session.commit()


api_agent = WFAgent(name="test")
db.session.add(api_agent)

api_agent = ApiAgent(name="test")
db.session.add(api_agent)

db.session.commit()
```

I got the following message :

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'app.models.agent.api_agent.ApiAgent' is not mapped
```

Did I break Sql Alchemy ? (I'm using sqlite)

Comment: I don't think you copied your code correctly. You should be getting a `NameError` in `api_agent.py` because `WFAgent` is not defined.

Comment: You right. I update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Got  it ! Thanks to Univerio, I check my import

This doesn't work

```
from agent.wf_agent import WFAgent
```

but

```
from .wf_agent import WFAgent
```

is ok !

Not sure to understand why ... I need to better understand how import works :)

Comment: This works simply coz the models are in the same directory. What if models are elsewhere and you need to put the full dotted path?